Qtest Testcycle API Get api request not able to pull more that two levels of Test cycles under a release
I am using QTest Tricentis to pull test cycles under any release, including its children and grandchild levels, through the following API:
GET /api/v3/projects/{projectId}/test-cycles?parentId={releaseId}&parentType=release&expand=descendants
This API call was working perfectly until two days ago. Previously, it would return all test cycles under a release, including all levels down to the grandchildren and beyond. However, now it only pulls two levels of test cycles (the immediate children and one more level), but nothing further.
Here’s an example of the API call I am using:
https://company.qtestnet.com/api/v3/projects/102646/test-cycles?parentId=1025927&parentType=release&expand=descendants
This URL used to return everything under the specific release, but now it only provides two levels of test cycles without drilling down further.
Has anything changed with the API? Am I missing something, or is there a new limitation? Any help would be appreciated.
